# React-native firebase cloud messaging. Can't receive remote messages in ios

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to enable push notifications for IOS in a react-native application. But even though firebase/send returns success message. The message itself does not seem to get received on the app.(I'm using a physical device to test it)

My package-lock looks like this:

```
 "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
 "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.3.3",
 "react-native-push-notification": "^7.2.3"
 "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.3.3",
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UNUserNotificationCenter.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

My AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];




#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif


  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"main"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  /*
  RCTBridge *bridge = [self.reactDelegate createBridgeWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"main"
                                            initialProperties:nil];
*/

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
//  UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewController];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}


- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

My podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
#require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

pre_install do |installer|
  Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}

  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-')
      def pod.build_type;
        # Uncomment the line corresponding to your CocoaPods version
        Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
        # Pod::Target::BuildType.static_library # < 1.9
      end
    end
  end
end

platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'MCRProfessionalApplication' do
  use_native_modules!
  use_modular_headers!
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  # Uncomment the code below to enable Flipper.
  #
  # You should not install Flipper in CI environments when creating release
  # builds, this will lead to significantly slower build times.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work.
  #
  #  use_flipper!
  #  post_install do |installer|
  #    flipper_post_install(installer)
  #  end

  pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

  pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'

  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

  pod 'RNScreens', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-screens'

  pod 'react-native-safe-area-context', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context'

  pod 'RNCMaskedView', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view'

  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

  pod 'RNSweetAlert', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sweet-alert'

  pod 'RNExitApp', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-exit-app'

  pod 'RNCCheckbox', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/checkbox'

  pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'

  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  pod 'Permission-AppTrackingTransparency', :path => "#{permissions_path}/AppTrackingTransparency"
  pod 'Permission-BluetoothPeripheral', :path => "#{permissions_path}/BluetoothPeripheral"
  pod 'Permission-Calendars', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Calendars"
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
  pod 'Permission-Contacts', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Contacts"
  pod 'Permission-FaceID', :path => "#{permissions_path}/FaceID"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAccuracy', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAccuracy"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"
  pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary"
  pod 'Permission-Microphone', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Microphone"
  pod 'Permission-Motion', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Motion"
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibraryAddOnly', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibraryAddOnly"
  pod 'Permission-Reminders', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Reminders"
  pod 'Permission-Siri', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Siri"
  pod 'Permission-SpeechRecognition', :path => "#{permissions_path}/SpeechRecognition"
  pod 'Permission-StoreKit', :path => "#{permissions_path}/StoreKit"

  pod 'react-native-geolocation', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation'

  pod 'RNSnackbar', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-snackbar'

  pod 'react-native-contacts', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-contacts'


  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'


  pod 'Folly', podspec: '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

    # React Native Maps dependencies
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

  require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")


end

post_install do |installer|
  ## Fix for XCode 12.5 beta
  find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
    "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")
  find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
    "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(strongModule))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(strongModule)))")
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
    end
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
    if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
      end
    end
  end
end

def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
      if text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```

my App.js looks like this

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar, Platform, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Navigation from '_navigations';
import { getCurrentCoordinations } from '_utils/geolocationUtils';
import messaging, {firebase} from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';


const App = () => {
    getCurrentCoordinations();




    useEffect(() => {

        const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {

            console.log(remoteMessage, '3');
            Platform.OS === 'android' &&
        PushNotification.localNotification({
            channelId: 'MyConstructor',
            message: remoteMessage.notification.body,
            title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
            smallIcon: 'ic_notification',
            largeIcon: 'ic_launcher',
            data: remoteMessage.data,
        });

            Platform.OS === 'ios' &&
                PushNotificationIOS.addNotificationRequest({
                    id: remoteMessage.messageId,
                    body: remoteMessage.notification.body,
                    title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
                    userInfo: remoteMessage.data,
                });
        });

        return unsubscribe;
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <StatusBar
                barStyle={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'light-content' : 'default'}
            />
            <Navigation />

        </View>
    );
};

export default App;
```

My index.js

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { AppState } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import * as RootNavigation from './src/navigations/RootNavigation.js';
import { navigationRef } from './src/navigations/RootNavigation.js';




PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
        channelId: 'MyConstructor', // (required)
        channelName: 'MyConstructor', // (required)
        playSound: false, // (optional) default: true
        soundName: 'default', // (optional) See `soundName` parameter of `localNotification` function
        vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true. Creates the default vibration pattern if true.
    },
    (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.
);

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
    console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
    console.log(remoteMessage, '2');
    Platform.OS === 'android' &&
    PushNotification.localNotification({
        channelId: 'MyConstructor',
        message: remoteMessage.notification.body,
        title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
        largeIcon: 'ic_launcher',
        smallIcon: 'ic_notification',
        data: remoteMessage.data,
    });

    Platform.OS === 'ios' &&
    PushNotificationIOS.addNotificationRequest({
        id: remoteMessage.messageId,
        body: remoteMessage.notification.body,
        title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
        userInfo: remoteMessage.data
    });
});

Must be outside of any component LifeCycle (such as `componentDidMount`).
PushNotification.configure({
    largeIcon: 'ic_launcher',
    smallIcon: 'ic_notification',
    // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
    onRegister: function (token) {
        console.log('TOKEN:', token);
    },

    // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
    onNotification: function (notification) {

        // let { screen, route_params } = notification.data;

        // route_params = typeof route_params === 'string' ? JSON?.parse(route_params) : route_params;

        // if (screen) {
        //     if (notification.foreground || AppState.currentState === 'background')
        //         RootNavigation.navigate(screen, route_params);
        //     else
        //         setTimeout(() => {
        //             RootNavigation.navigate(screen, route_params);
        //         }, 4000);
        // }
        // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
    },

    // (optional) Called when Registered Action is pressed and invokeApp is false, if true onNotification will be called (Android)
    onAction: function (notification) {
        console.log('ACTION:', notification.action);
        console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
    // process the action
    },

    // (optional) Called when the user fails to register for remote notifications. Typically occurs when APNS is having issues, or the device is a simulator. (iOS)
    onRegistrationError: function (err) {
        console.error(err.message, err);
    },

    // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
    permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
    },

    // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
    // default: true
    popInitialNotification: true,

    /**
   * (optional) default: true
   * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
   * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
   * - if you are not using remote notification or do not have Firebase installed, use this:
   *     requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
   */
    requestPermissions: true,
});

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in the Expo client or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);
```

Apns certificate is set up in the firebase console and all the required capabilities are checked both in apple console and in xcode.
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Forgot to mention GoogleService-Info.plist is also in place

Comment: Does your FCM Token get's generated? I'm in a very similar issue. I also did a side app just to implement RNFirebase Cloud messaging, using a different bundle id and it worked, messages were delivered. I'm still looking for solutions which not require changing the bundle id.